# Can't delete google cloud sql replication master instance

Tags: mysql, sql-server, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I decided to play around with Google Could SQL and I setup a test sql instance, loaded it with some data and then setup replication on it in the google dev console. I did my testing and found out it all works great, the master/slave setup works as it should and my little POC was a success. So now I want to delete the POC sql instances but that's not going so well.

I deleted the replica instance fine (aka the 'slave') but for some reason the master instance still thinks there is a slave and therefore will not let me delete it. For example I run the following command in the gclound shell:

```
gcloud sql instances delete MY-INSTANCE-NAME
```

I get the following message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.delete) The requested operation is not valid for a replication master instance.
```

This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWmyp.png) also shows that in the google dev console it clearly thinks there are no replicas attached to this instance (because I deleted them) but when I run:

```
gcloud sql instances describe MY-INSTANCE-NAME
```

It shows that there is a replica name still attached to the instance.

Any ideas on how to delete this for good? Kinda lame to keep on paying for this when it was just a POC that I want to delete (glad I didn't pick a high memory machine!)

Comment: This looks to my like a bug on the UI, not showing the replicas properly. Did you try deleting the replica using the `gcloud` command line tool?

Comment: Good idea. Just tried deleting it and no dice. It returns `ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.delete) The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request.` when I put in the describe command for the replica instance I get back `ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) The Cloud SQL instance does not exist. `

Comment: Apologies, sounds like something went wrong on our end. Please send the project and instance name to cloud-sql@google.com and we will investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was on Google's side and they fixed it. Here were the sequence of events that led to the issue happening:
1) Change master's tier
2) Promote replica to master while the master tier change is in progress

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem using GCloud.  Deleting the failover replica first and then the master instance worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**dont use any google product.**

all the products are not stable.
are products are poorly coded.
have many problems and latency.
they are all at development stage.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34494782)